# allow access to ssh and proftp from LAN and one external IP

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, ftp

I would like to allow access to my linux (debian) via ssh and proftp from whole LAN (192.168.1.x) and one external IP (external ip is always associated with my sub.dom.tld).
I found this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18939285/how-to-access-my-ssh-linux-server-from-outside-my-home-network but I would like to maintain external IP fresh (from time to time it can be changed so I simply set new ip address on my domain name for this subdomain and my linux box should update this restriction by itself automatically).

Is there any way, how to restrict access to my linux for ssh and proftp just for that external IP and for whole LAN?

if step by step tutorial is available, great. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of possible ways to do that, some are simple and bad (`tcp_wrappers`), some are better and complicated (`iptables`), some are simple and basically the same good (`firewalld`)

1. TCP wrappers (aka `hosts_access`), you probably need [`mod_wrap`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_wrap.html) module to ProFTPd. In SSHD it works fine so far.

   ```
   /etc/hosts.deny:
     ALL: ALL

   /etc/hosts.allow:
     sshd, proftpd: 192.168., 1.2.3.4
   ```

   if your LAN is `192.168.0.0/16` and your external IP is `1.2.3.4`
2. Firewalld is using `iptables` is more fancy, since they blocks it on network level:

   ```
   firewall-cmd --zone=internal --add-service=ssh
   firewall-cmd --zone=internal --add-service=ftp
   firewall-cmd --zone=internal --add-source=192.168.0.0/16
   firewall-cmd --zone=internal --add-source=1.2.3.4/32
   firewall-cmd --zone=public --remove-service=ssh
   firewall-cmd --zone=public --remove-service=ftp
   ```

   [(Source)](https://serverfault.com/questions/680780/block-all-but-a-few-ips-with-firewalld)

Comment: thank you Jakuje. I like idea with firewalld. But how can I keep external IP updated if it changes?

Comment: not sure about `firewalld`, but `tcp_wrappers` certainly accept also hostnames.

Comment: I'll try `tcp_wrappers`, but maybe I should put comma between 192.168. and 1.2.3.4

Comment: Yes, you are right. There was missing comma. Fixed now.

Comment: I tried to set it right now in hosts.allow like "sshd, proftpd: 192.168., sub.domain.com". Everything works, but it checks reverse lookup for incoming connection from external IP if it validates with sub.domain.com. But how should I set it this way -> my server should check IP address of sub.domain.com, and if IP of incoming connection is the same as sub.domain.com, then allow access. I am not able to set reverse lookup for ip address to be sub.domain.com, but I am able to set IP address for subdomain sub.domain.com.

Comment: In this case. It is probably not possible. I would rather give a try some "port knocking tool" or `fwknop`. But it is too long to describe in the comments here.

Comment: thanks. I am thinking about solution, that I set cronjob for checking IP of sub.domain.com and rewrite hosts.allow file with actual IP.

Comment: Yes. It might be easier and autonomous way :)